# Heart Rate Value is fetched when the Android wear watch is not worn

Tags: wear-os

I wrote Android wear app to fetch heart rate from Moto 360. I tested the app it works fine. But to my curiosity, the heart rate value (value is 60+ consistently) is displayed when the watch is not worn. Then I wore the watch and the heart rate goes up to 80+. I tested the values against moto Body heart rate, my app gives the same value. How can I restrict the values to be fetched only when the watch is worn?

Comment: Does the Moto 360 have a GSR sensor? Does it give raw HR sensor data? Either of those could be analyzed.

Comment: There is one sensor at the back of the watch. Not sure is that GSR.

Comment: look into that, as that's likely the main purpose of the GSR if the 360 has one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the sensor manager? You should be able to simple keep a track of accuracy with onAccuarryChanged. When it reports SENSOR_STATUS_NO_CONTACT you know to ignore the results.

Comment: The watch is not worn but still it gives the accuracy as low, medium or high (the values are 1,2,3 respectively) . Not even once, it gave the response as NO CONTACT..

Comment: Hmm must be bad manufacturer implementation, works on my moto 360 sport.